# Fixed points and system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, fixed-point-theorems

Suppose that $F : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. A fixed-point of function $F$ is such that
$$
F(x) = x.
$$
We can represent that fixed point as the solution to the system
$$
F(x) - x = 0.
$$
My question is whether all systems of equations have a fixed-point representation. My intuition is that it depends on whether the system is "separable" in the sense that given a system
$$
G(x) = 0,
$$
we can find a function $F$ such that $G(x) = F(x) - x$. Is that so? Are there any conditions on $G$ that guarantee that?

Comment: How about $F(x)=G(x)+x$?

Comment: my god, so trivial... this is when i know i need a break :)